# Adding user to group after running New-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

So I'm coming tot he end of my first powershell project, I have been creating a script to import users into active directory from a CSV file containing only first and surnames.

```
Import-Csv users.csv |
    select Surname,
        @{n='GivenName';e={$_.'FirstName'}},
        @{n='samaccountname';e={$_.FirstName.substring(0,2) + $_.Surname}},
        @{n='UserPrincipalName';e={$_.FirstName.substring(0,2) + $_.Surname}},
        @{n='Name';e={$_.'FirstName' + ' ' + $_.'Surname'}} |
    New-ADUser -Enabled $true -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "Password1" -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Path "OU=Intake 20XX,OU=Students,OU=Ravenloft users,DC=RAVENLOFT,DC=test" -ProfilePath {"\\TESTSVR\Profiles$\Intake20XX\" +$_.SamAccountName} -HomeDrive "D:" -HomeDirectory {"\\TESTSVR\Work$\Intake20XX\" +$_.SamAccountName}
```

Now my last job for this would be to add all of these new users to a group called StudentGroup, I understand there is no parameter in new-aduser to edit the "Member of" field in AD. So what would be the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: `New-ADUser ... -PassThru |Foreach-Object {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "DN of StudentGroup" -Members $_}`

Comment: @Mathias R. Jessen Brilliant, thanks mate, that's got it sorted. Time to go research some more into -Passthru.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to do this on two separate lines

```
New-ADUser ...
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "name_of_group" -Members "username"
```

If you want to one line it, credit goes to Mathias's comment  (using `-PassThru`)

```
New-ADUser ... -PassThru | % {Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "DN of StudentGroup" -Members $_}
```

How you fit that into your script is up to you

`-Members` can accept an array or a single string of username

```
New-ADUser ...
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "name_of_group" -Members @("username1","username2")
```