# Windows Server 2016: Bulk create user accounts in an OU

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory, virtual-machine

I am very new to server management and I need to create 500 user accounts. I created a .csv file for the users' details. Here is what it looks like. 
[image: Image of .CSV file in Excel]

I have copied this file onto my Virtual Machine, in my C: drive as hr-names.csv
On my VM, this is how it looks like.
[image: Image of .CSV file in my VM, opened on notepad]

I need the users to all be created inside G HR group. I have opened up the properties of the attribute and copied the path which is

> **CN=G HR,OU=HR,OU=Zara Pte Ltd,DC=frontier,DC=net**

[image: path from active directory users and computers]
[image: attribute from the properties window]

I have been trying to run the this code, but to no avail. It keeps creating users inside my users container, and not inside my G HR Group.

```
# Import active directory module for running AD cmdlets
Import-Module activedirectory

#Store the data from ADUsers.csv in the $ADUsers variable
$ADUsers = Import-csv C:\hr-names.csv

#Loop through each row containing user details in the CSV file 
foreach ($User in $ADUsers)
{
    #Read user data from each field in each row and assign the data to a variable as below

    $Username   = $User.username
    $Password   = $User.password
    $Firstname  = $User.firstname
    $OU         = $User.ou #This field refers to the OU the user account is to be created in
    $Password = $User.Password


    #Check to see if the user already exists in AD
    if (Get-ADUser -F {SamAccountName -eq $Username})
    {
         #If user does exist, give a warning
         Write-Warning "A user account with username $Username already exist in Active Directory."
    }
    else
    {
        #User does not exist then proceed to create the new user account

        #Account will be created in the OU provided by the $OU variable read from the CSV file
        New-ADUser `
            -SamAccountName $Username `
            -UserPrincipalName "$Username@frontier.net" `
            -Name "$Firstname" 
            -GivenName $Firstname
            -Path $OU `
            -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False 
    }
}
```

It also produces this error but then occasionally creates some of the accounts inside the Users container:
[image: error code]
[image: created users in the wrong place]

I need help on creating a powershell/cmd code that can help me create 500 users using my .csv file and allows all the users to belong to the G HR group.

**EDIT: @Rup has pointed out to me that I need to first add users into the OU before I can add them to the group. However, I am still unsure of how to add my users to my HR OU. They are being added to the Users container.**

**EDIT 2: I can't figure out how to add my users to my G HR group at once. Tried the link that @Rup kindly provided for other users that I manually created but didn't work**

Comment: The OU is the path to create the user object in in AD. If you want to make them members of a group then that's not the same thing.

Comment: Probably what you want: [Adding user to group after running New-ADUser](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36060176/243245)

Comment: @Rup so should I create it in an OU then use a separate powershell code to add it into the group?

Comment: @Rup currently all the users are being created inside the user group and not even the hr group. is there anyway i can change that?

Comment: *"the users are being created inside the user group"* - That's not a thing that happens. Users cannot be "created" in a group. Users are created in an OU. Then existing users are added a members to a group.

Comment: But the error about the `-GivenName` is simply because you are missing the backtick (`\``) at the end of the line above it, so PowerShell thinks that `-GivenName` is a new command.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing ` on -Name and -GiveName which tells powershell that the even though there on seperate lines there still apart of the New-ADUser cmdlet not a new cmdlet. You could also just have all the New-ADUser on one line of code like below;

`New-ADUser -SamAccountName $Username -UserPrincipalName "$Username@frontier.net" -Name "$Firstname" -GivenName $Firstname -Path $OU -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False`

Or use the code below

```
New-ADUser `
    -SamAccountName $Username `
    -UserPrincipalName "$Username@frontier.net" `
    -Name $Firstname `
    -GivenName $Firstname `
    -Path $OU `
    -AccountPassword (convertto-securestring $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False
```

}

Hope this helps

Comment: That's only the first problem. Once this is fixed, it's going to give a different error because the value being passed to `-Path` is not an OU.

Comment: @GabrielLuci so how do i ensure that my path is right? Should it just be OU=HR,OU=Zara Pte Ltd,DC=frontier,DC=net ?

Comment: If that's the OU you want them in. Only you can answer that :)